# Not returning nan for two vars

Tags: jquery, calculator, nan

I've stopped my boxes displaying nan for the top two boxes when letters are entered into them. I when enter in letters into the third box and then a number into box 1. or 2. I get nan. Its probably really easy but I can't work it out?

```
1.<input type="text" id="first"/>
2.<input type="text" id="second" />
3.<input type="text" id="third" value="10"/>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 5;

    $('#first').keyup(function(){ 
        var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val());
        var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());
        if(!isNaN(firstValue))
        var hi = $('#second').val(firstValue * thirdValue / num);
    });

    $('#second').keyup(function(){
        var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val());
        var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());
        if(!isNaN(secondValue))  
        $('#first').val(secondValue / num * thirdValue);
    });

    $('#third').keyup(function(){
        var firstValue = parseFloat($('#first').val());
        var secondValue = parseFloat($('#second').val());
        var thirdValue = parseFloat($('#third').val());
        if(!isNaN(thirdValue)) 
        $('#first').val(secondValue / num * thirdValue);
        if(!isNaN(thirdValue))
        $('#second').val(firstValue * thirdValue / num);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n00bctrl/vory55ze/#&togetherjs=bffzvEK5wS

Answer (score 0):

First and second boxes you aren't checking to see if the third box isNaN.

```
if(!isNaN(Val1))  ==>  if(!isNaN(Val1) && !isNaN(Val3))

if(!isNaN(Val2))  ==> if(!isNaN(Val2) && !isNaN(Val3))
```

Try with above change.